# Solution verification for determining how many numbers in a set that are prime to a particular number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I have this problem:
Find total numbers in the set contains integers from 0 to 799 that are relatively prime to 800.

My solution is: 800 - (numbers that are divisible by 2 or 5) = 800 - (400+160-80) = 320.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  But as the point of  the exercise is for you, the student, to demonstrate that you understand and can apply the inclusion/exclusion principal, for style point you ought to point out that 400 = # of numbers divisible by 2; 160 = # of numbers divisible by 5; and 60 = # of numbers divisible by 10.  Although it is obvious that that is what you meant.

Comment: For *thorough* style "talk to me like I'm five" style points you could write: "$800 -$ (#numbers that are divisible by 2 or 5) = $800 - $[#numbers that are divisible by 2+ #numbers that are divisible by 5-#numbers that are divisible by both 2 and 5] = $800$ - [#numbers that are divisible by 2+#divisible by 5-#divisible by 10] = $800 - (\frac {800}2 + \frac {800}5 - \frac {800}{10}) =    800 - (400+160-80) = 320$.  Or maybe that is just overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job, the approach and the answer is correct.

Short python code to verify the answer:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)
counter = 0  
for i in range(800):
    if gcd(i,800) == 1:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```